# js сравнить 2 строки побуквеннно

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы сравнивало 1 с 1, 2 с 2 буквой, а не 1 со всеми 2 строки

```
   var array1 = "1234",
       array2 = "143421";


    var cache;
    var cache2;

    var ln1 = array1.length
    ln2 = array2.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < ln1; ++i)
    {
        cache = array1[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < ln2; ++j)
        {
            cache2 =array2[j];
            if (cache == array2[j])
            {
                console.log('найдено совпадение: ' + cache);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array1 = "1234",
    array2 = "143421";

var ln;
if (array1.length > array2.length) ln = array1.length; else ln = array2.length;


for (var i = 0; i < ln; i++)
{
    if (array1[i] == array2[i]) {
        console.log('найдено совпадение: ' + i);
        break;
    }
}
```